# Unhiding many hidden names is crashing Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Excel is crashing every time I run the below code.

I'm trying to unhide names. There are a lot of them. I tried to copy a sheet and it took me forever to get rid of the name conflict messages.

Is there a way to unhide only some names at a time so Excel doesn't crash?

```
Sub Show_Hidden_Defined_Names()

Dim xName As Variant

For Each xName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    xName.Visible = True
Next xName

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you debugged you code to see if there is a specific name that *"crashes"* Excel? And what do you mean with *"crash"*? Runtime error? Hangs forever? Really crashes and needs to be restarted?

Answer (score 0):

Some names (particularly those that start with "_") are defined based on certain newer functions being used in your workbook or things like print regions. See if avoiding those will help:

```
Sub Show_Hidden_Defined_Names()
  Dim xName As Name
  For Each xName In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If Left$(xName.Name, 1) <> "_" Then xName.Visible = True
  Next
End Sub
```

Also, as shown above, it's a good idea in most cases to use `ThisWorkbook` rather than `ActiveWorkbook`. The latter refers to whichever workbook has focus, the former, to the one that contains the VBA code. They may not always be the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still crashing but thank you for the suggestion. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to see which `Name` causes the crash

```
Sub Show_Hidden_Defined_Names()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim s As String:s = "No errors"
    Dim xName As Name
    For Each xName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        xName.Visible = True
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            s = xName.Name
            Exit For
        End If
    Next xName
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```